# EC don`t work with locators from another file

Tags: python, selenium, expected-condition

I am trying to seporate my locators from page object classes. And it works perfectry with driver.find_element. But if i an trying to use it with EC, like `self.wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(*OrderLocators.file_upload_in_process))`

I get this error

```
File "C:\FilePath\ClabtFirstForm.py", line 95, in wait_for_file_upload
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(*OrderLocators.file_upload_in_process))
TypeError: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

My test method

```
def test_files_regular(self):
    project_path = get_project_path()
    file = project_path + "\Data\Media\doc_15mb.doc"
    self.order.button_upload_files()
    self.order.button_select_files(file)
    self.order.wait_for_file_upload()
```

Page object class

```
class CreateOrder(object):

def __init__(self, driver):
    self.driver = driver
    self.wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 25)

def button_upload_files(self):
    self.driver.find_element(*OrderLocators.button_upload_files).click()

def button_select_files(self, file):
    self.driver.find_element(*OrderLocators.button_select_files).send_keys(file)

def wait_for_file_upload(self):
    self.wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(*OrderLocators.file_upload_in_process))
    self.wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[ng-show='item.isSuccess']")))
```

Locators

```
class OrderLocators(object):

    button_upload_files = (By.CLASS_NAME, 'file-upload-label')
    button_select_files = (By.CLASS_NAME, 'input-file')
    file_upload_in_process = (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[ng-show='item.isUploading']")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are passing the arguments to `visibility_of_element_located()`with `*`, you're in fact passing the expanded iterable `OrderLocators.file_upload_in_process`. That is, this call:

```
visibility_of_element_located(*OrderLocators.file_upload_in_process)
```

, is the same as:

```
visibility_of_element_located(By.CLASS_NAME, 'input-file')
```

Note how in the second line the method is actually called with two arguments.

In the same time, this condition's [constructor expects only a single argument](https://github.com/browserstack/selenium-webdriver-python/blob/master/selenium/webdriver/support/expected_conditions.py#L60) - a tuple/list of two elements; thus the exception.

The fix - pass to it what it expects, the tuple itself, without expending it:

```
visibility_of_element_located(OrderLocators.file_upload_in_process)
```